# Why my NLP model has tagged wrong word as a new entity?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm new to NLP. Working on this from last 2/3 days. Using `spacy` for this. I'm trying to "train an additional entity type" by using the following piece of code...

```
"""Example of training an additional entity type

This script shows how to add a new entity type to an existing pre-trained NER
model. To keep the example short and simple, only four sentences are provided
as examples. In practice, you'll need many more — a few hundred would be a
good start. You will also likely need to mix in examples of other entity
types, which might be obtained by running the entity recognizer over unlabelled
sentences, and adding their annotations to the training set.

The actual training is performed by looping over the examples, and calling
`nlp.entity.update()`. The `update()` method steps through the words of the
input. At each word, it makes a prediction. It then consults the annotations
provided on the GoldParse instance, to see whether it was right. If it was
wrong, it adjusts its weights so that the correct action will score higher
next time.

After training your model, you can save it to a directory. We recommend
wrapping models as Python packages, for ease of deployment.

For more details, see the documentation:
* Training: https://spacy.io/usage/training
* NER: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities

Compatible with: spaCy v2.1.0+
Last tested with: v2.1.0
"""
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function

import plac
import random
from pathlib import Path
import spacy
from spacy.util import minibatch, compounding


# new entity label
LABEL = "CATID:1000012"

# training data
# Note: If you're using an existing model, make sure to mix in examples of
# other entity types that spaCy correctly recognized before. Otherwise, your
# model might learn the new type, but "forget" what it previously knew.
# https://explosion.ai/blog/pseudo-rehearsal-catastrophic-forgetting
TRAIN_DATA = [
    (
        "The mobile phone can be used to communicate over long distances without wires.",
        {"entities": [(11, 16, LABEL)]},
    ),
    (
        "A smartphone is a mobile phone that can do more than other phones.",
        {"entities": [(2, 12, LABEL)]},
    ),
    (
        "Feature phones run on proprietary firmware with third-party software support through platforms such as Java ME or BREW.",
        {"entities": [(8, 14, LABEL)]},
    ),
    (
        "As mobile phones became more popular, they began to cost less money, and more people could afford them.",
        {"entities": [(10, 16, LABEL)]},
    ),
    (
        "The majority of smartphones run on Apple iOS or Google Android but others use Windows Phone or BlackBerry OS.",
        {"entities": [(16, 27, LABEL)]},
    ),
    (
        "Feature phones are often more durable, less complex, and more affordable.",
        {"entities": [(8, 14, LABEL)]},
    ),
]


@plac.annotations(
    model=("Model name. Defaults to blank 'en' model.", "option", "m", str),
    new_model_name=("New model name for model meta.", "option", "nm", str),
    output_dir=("Optional output directory", "option", "o", Path),
    n_iter=("Number of training iterations", "option", "n", int),
)
def main(model="en_core_web_sm", new_model_name="CATID", output_dir="Model", n_iter=30):
    """Set up the pipeline and entity recognizer, and train the new entity."""
    random.seed(0)
    if model is not None:
        nlp = spacy.load(model)  # load existing spaCy model
        print("Loaded model '%s'" % model)
    else:
        nlp = spacy.blank("en")  # create blank Language class
        print("Created blank 'en' model")
    # Add entity recognizer to model if it's not in the pipeline
    # nlp.create_pipe works for built-ins that are registered with spaCy
    if "ner" not in nlp.pipe_names:
        ner = nlp.create_pipe("ner")
        nlp.add_pipe(ner)
    # otherwise, get it, so we can add labels to it
    else:
        ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")

    ner.add_label(LABEL)  # add new entity label to entity recognizer
    # Adding extraneous labels shouldn't mess anything up
    ner.add_label("VEGETABLE")
    if model is None:
        optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
    else:
        optimizer = nlp.resume_training()
    move_names = list(ner.move_names)
    # get names of other pipes to disable them during training
    other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != "ner"]
    with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train NER
        sizes = compounding(1.0, 4.0, 1.001)
        # batch up the examples using spaCy's minibatch
        for itn in range(n_iter):
            random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
            batches = minibatch(TRAIN_DATA, size=sizes)
            losses = {}
            for batch in batches:
                texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
                nlp.update(texts, annotations, sgd=optimizer,
                        drop=0.35, losses=losses)
            print("Losses", losses)

    # test the trained model
    test_text = "Mobile phones under 10k."
    doc = nlp(test_text)
    print("Entities in '%s'" % test_text)
    for ent in doc.ents:
        print(ent.label_, ent.text)

    # save model to output directory
    if output_dir is not None:
        output_dir = Path(output_dir)
        if not output_dir.exists():
            output_dir.mkdir()
        nlp.meta["name"] = new_model_name  # rename model
        nlp.to_disk(output_dir)
        print("Saved model to", output_dir)

        # test the saved model
        print("Loading from", output_dir)
        nlp2 = spacy.load(output_dir)
        # Check the classes have loaded back consistently
        assert nlp2.get_pipe("ner").move_names == move_names
        doc2 = nlp2(test_text)
        for ent in doc2.ents:
            print(ent.label_, ent.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    plac.call(main)
```

What I've done at here is, created a new entity by the name "CATID:1000012" & trying to teach the existing model(en_core_web_sm) by providing some training data to identify the new entity(`CATID:1000012`).

But, after training when I use the statement(`Mobile phones under 10k.`) for testing to identifying the new entity I'm getting word `under` tagged as my new entity. I Can't able to understand why it's happening.

Here is the output of the training result for reference.

```
nlp python train_new_entity_type.py 
Loaded model 'en_core_web_sm'
Losses {'ner': 97.52074194946908}
Losses {'ner': 93.69056796826771}
Losses {'ner': 104.9913784135133}
Losses {'ner': 106.799345289357}
Losses {'ner': 95.95352823211579}
Losses {'ner': 95.5921512588784}
Losses {'ner': 104.20201236551293}
Losses {'ner': 91.30133426242173}
Losses {'ner': 83.3817401985325}
Losses {'ner': 108.10902537551738}
Losses {'ner': 90.79526191594738}
Losses {'ner': 92.66721615749748}
Losses {'ner': 89.48430367704572}
Losses {'ner': 79.65045529220826}
Losses {'ner': 81.69409873239893}
Losses {'ner': 78.08388914307191}
Losses {'ner': 75.96670668302312}
Losses {'ner': 85.84131752077208}
Losses {'ner': 83.16802654485699}
Losses {'ner': 74.70389228454836}
Losses {'ner': 82.74640468226158}
Losses {'ner': 86.27583874967632}
Losses {'ner': 91.80043086154723}
Losses {'ner': 71.57743340098828}
Losses {'ner': 89.68161530740633}
Losses {'ner': 68.54411317529383}
Losses {'ner': 79.08097473334223}
Losses {'ner': 80.63091049017571}
Losses {'ner': 87.19688005072365}
Losses {'ner': 87.32719076574251}
Entities in 'Mobile phones under 10k.'
CATID:1000012 phones
CATID:1000012 under
CATID:1000012 .
Saved model to Model
Loading from Model
CATID:1000012 phones
CATID:1000012 under
VEGETABLE .
```

Answer (score 2):

In the code you shared, there is the comment:

```
# training data
# Note: If you're using an existing model, make sure to mix in examples of
# other entity types that spaCy correctly recognized before. Otherwise, your
# model might learn the new type, but "forget" what it previously knew.
# https://explosion.ai/blog/pseudo-rehearsal-catastrophic-forgetting
```

You are providing a super small amount of new examples and training a large number of times on them, likely causing great harm to what pretraining your model had. You need a larger number of samples for your new entity, and to mix the new samples with the old ones to preserve the knowledge of the model.

Answer (score 0):

TRAIN_DATA require following changes:

```
    ...
    (
        "A smartphone is a mobile phone that can do more than other phones.",
        {"entities": [(2, 12, LABEL),(25, 30, LABEL),(59, 65, LABEL)]},
    ),
    ...
    (
        "The majority of smartphones run on Apple iOS or Google Android but others use Windows Phone or BlackBerry OS.",
        {"entities": [(16, 27, LABEL),(86, 91, LABEL)]},
    ),
    ...
```

Here is the output of the training result:

```
Loaded model 'en_core_web_sm'
Losses {'ner': 83.72789190811926}
Losses {'ner': 96.47575069361687}
Losses {'ner': 56.43584463628454}
Losses {'ner': 59.22420631077148}
Losses {'ner': 41.63308255611264}
Losses {'ner': 68.9472689696122}
Losses {'ner': 65.6750720918717}
Losses {'ner': 51.220921694126446}
Losses {'ner': 74.63427307200618}
Losses {'ner': 62.71787362790201}
Losses {'ner': 61.84169684245717}
Losses {'ner': 61.28642024018336}
Losses {'ner': 56.87159592239186}
Losses {'ner': 66.16683439421467}
Losses {'ner': 78.72227119281888}
Losses {'ner': 50.78606884623878}
Losses {'ner': 62.62184074555989}
Losses {'ner': 56.0269543392933}
Losses {'ner': 60.42498599970713}
Losses {'ner': 46.94990211768891}
Losses {'ner': 55.336593621366774}
Losses {'ner': 53.165970050722535}
Losses {'ner': 61.689960623771185}
Losses {'ner': 54.042556638929454}
Losses {'ner': 88.83415890859033}
Losses {'ner': 62.481123548859614}
Losses {'ner': 64.13814233476296}
Losses {'ner': 74.48746071499772}
Losses {'ner': 60.02015231807627}
Losses {'ner': 62.56470086690388}
Entities in 'Mobile phones under 10k.'
CATID:1000012 phones
Saved model to Model
Loading from Model
CATID:1000012 phones
```